# DNS problems on Android

Tags: android, dns

I had gotten reports from a few users that they couldn't login to our app (which makes HTTP calls to our site) or visit our website in their browser, so I added some code to our latest build to check what IP our host name is resolving to.  I've gotten reports from several different users now that they get 127.0.0.1 for our hostname when the app starts, which obviously isn't going to work.

They claim they aren't running any proxy software, and this happens on both 2.1 and 2.2.  This also happens on both wifi & 3g, which makes me suspect it is some piece of software on their phone that is interfering with DNS resolution somehow.  Does anyone know of any popular software that might do that?  Or does anyone have any ideas about how to identify which software might be doing it?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you know which ISP they use? It might the ISP itself to block some address by putting a fake zone into their DNS.
AFAIK, the only way to force an address to be  resolved into 127.0.0.1 via software  is by write an entry into  the /etc/host file and it can be done only on a rooted phone

Comment: Can you share the code you added to get that kind of info?

Comment: Macarse, I just do InetAddress.getByName(hostname), after checking if the network is up with getActiveNetworkInfo

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.xbill.DNS.Lookup;
import org.xbill.DNS.Record;
import org.xbill.DNS.TXTRecord;
import org.xbill.DNS.TextParseException;
import org.xbill.DNS.Type;

public class DNSLookUpActivity extends Activity {
    private String url = "https://spectracore.americanlogistics.com/rdac/AdmissionController/CheckMddAdmission";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        funDNS(url);

    }

    private static void funDNS(String url) {

        try {
            Lookup lookup = new Lookup(url, Type.ANY);
            Record[] records = lookup.run();

            if (lookup.getResult() == Lookup.SUCCESSFUL) {
                String responseMessage = null;
                String listingType = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                    if (records[i] instanceof TXTRecord) {
                        TXTRecord txt = (TXTRecord) records[i];
                        for (Iterator j = txt.getStrings().iterator(); j
                                .hasNext();) {
                            responseMessage += (String) j.next();
                        }
                        Log.e("TXRecord ", "" + responseMessage);
                    } else if (records[i] instanceof ARecord) {
                        listingType = ((ARecord) records[i]).getAddress()
                                .getHostAddress();
                        Log.e("ARecord address : ", "" + listingType);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (TextParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
Need android ask version 2.3.3 or above
```

Answer (score 0):

Get their DNS config, and try their DNS servers directly with dig or nslookup. This is not perfect, but it has a good chance of showing you the problem.

Answer (score 0):

dnsjava/org.xbill.DNS is too big for android app, Scott Means's DNSQuery is promiseful:

http://smeans.com/programming/dns-queries-in-java/